# Azure KeyVault: SPN KeyVault Access Denied

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am using below Azure Powershell command in VSTS.

```
(Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -vaultName "debugkv" -name "CoreConfig-StorageAccount-AccessKey")
```

I am getting  ##[error]Access denied error while running it in VSTS but loclaly it works fine.

I have added the SPN in KV's access policies also with GET and SET permissions for secrets.

Need help in troubleshooting it.

Comment: Are you running through PowerShell in VSTS or Azure PowerShell. It needs to be the latter.

Comment: Azure Powershell, Actually in KV I see two entries with the same name and I think PowerShell is registering wrong one in access policies so not sure how to pick correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link VSTS to you need to give the Service Principal, which forms the Service Endpoint in VSTS, access to the Key Vault; you already know this.

What can be confusing is that you can assign the application and the service principal to have access to the key vault depending on your use case. Therefore, you must ensure that you assign the right object to the access policy.

The best way to ensure you assign the right object is to do it through Azure Powershell.

Running a signed in Azure Powershell session:

```
$spObjectId = Get-AzureRmAdServicePrincipal -SearchString <ServicePrincipalName> | Foreach-Object {$_.Id}

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName <VaultName> -ObjectId $spObjectId -PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set
```

If you wanted to see further details (objectids, permissions etc) of the access policies you can get these through Powershell also:

```
Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName <VaultName> | Foreach-Object {$_.AccessPolicies}
```

Comment: After the RCA I found that I have to provide the enterprise application object id from aad and not the app registration id, your answer helped me in troubleshooting. thanks